# How to change STRING Id to a new INT Id?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

I would like to use an extension in PostgreSQL, which does not work with STRING or CHAR Ids. I have already a .sql-Script to create all the tables and all .backups for these tables, which have some columns with string ids.

The idea is to load the tables with the values and then to add a new column with Unique INT Ids for every String id. There are some same values of string ids in some tuples, that's why I can't create a new serial int.

How is it possible to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: dense_rank with a new column

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your data is as follows:

```
Stringid  ||   data 
1         ||   as
1         ||    aslh
1         ||    akk
2         ||    abb
2         ||    as
```

Your query have to be :

```
    Select Stringid, data,
    Row_number()over(partition by
 Stringid order by Stringid as) as id 
from tab1;
```

Output:

```
Stringid  ||     data   ||      id
1         ||     as     ||       1 
1         ||     aslh   ||       2 
1         ||     akk    ||       3 
2         ||     abb    ||       1 
2         ||     as     ||       2
```

Comment: I have to use this new id in the next queries too. That is why i have to add this column to my old table and to delete the stringId

Comment: First of all is that the result you need or not? If not provide me more details and we will sort it out 

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! It is the result I needed